# remote debugging- chrome on IOS via mac

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

I want to do a remote debugging for a website on Chrome in a IOS device.

I found many solutions out there, but none of them give me the utility to do remote debug.

Technical parameters:

1. The website is running on IOS 15, Chrome
2. I want to debug it from my mac.
3. I want to debug it from Chrome and not safari
4. I want to see the network, this is why I need a remote debugging and not just logs.

I know that there are many questions about this issue, but all of them from the year 2014 and below.